# Create action through "organizations" and "membership" models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a rails app with "organizations" and "membership" models. Orgs have many users through memberships, and vice versa.

Orgs also have many events and every event belongs to an org.  In fact, events must belong to an org.

Assuming a user has membership in more than one org, how do I enable them to create a new event for the right organization?

I want to avoid nested routes such as organization/1/event/new. Also I want to avoid asking the user to select the org in a dropdown menu.... is there a third way?

Comment: well maybe let the user choose the org from the drop down menu ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady that is a reasonable suggestion and I should have mentioned I'm looking to know if there's a third way, besides nested routes or dropdown menu. Will edit hte question.

Comment: I can't really think of a third way, why do you want a different way?

Comment: "Follow" or "join" the organization with a button to see the members, info, etc